The difference between ii°7 and vii°7

Hello my friends,
I cannot understand the difference between these two chords. I have probably misunderstood the whole thing, but I don't know how to function or choose between these two chords, because ii°7 is literally an inversion and enharmonic to vii°7.
And also in ii°7, how do I resolve the seventh down if I wanna lead it to the tonic (or I better just write a vii°7 that includes leading tone)?

The difference is functional. A diminished (seventh) chord built on scale degree 7 is presumed to resolve to the tonic chord — as noted. An apparent iio7 that resolves to I/i would be presumed to be a vii chord enharmonically spelled.
Another possibility is that a seeming iio7 would resolve to III, but in that case, it would be labelled as vii/III.
A fully diminished ii chord, on the other hand "doesn't exist" in functional theory, because it can't be formed by pitches from the major or minor scale. Specifically, ♭1 isn't part of any major/minor scale. Such a chord could only come from another key.
A hypothetical exception might be a situation in which the chord was serving as a common-tone chord connecting two ii chords (most likely in a major key). Some theorists might label it as a ii chord, while others would label it C.T. (in particular, Steven Laitz, author of The Complete Musician, a standard music theory textbook).

Thank you so much , so i understood that ii°7 doesn't function if we want a dominant and if it's there it's the vii°7/III . I also didn't know about the C.T's i looked it up and one question came up ? If C.T's are mostly used in modern songs and romantic  . Then the raised chromatic tones in mozart and bethoveen must be the Aug6

The passing tones (raised ) in classical pieces seem to have this augmented six function but some of them have no function at all ( none functional passing tones are so common in romantic era but does that apply to classical eras to?) Sorry none related questions

@user98606 In the Romantic era, as composers introduced more and more chromaticism and moved increasingly away from the tonal system, they began using chords in unexpected ways. It's certainly possible that a iio7 was used to move to a V chord via some non-standard motion in the pitches, but it would be very much the exception. Regarding common tone chords, try this search of the site.
